# Parsing JSON array in Swift with array root object

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I am attempting to parse a json array with the format:

```
 [{"id":1,"date":1596827226.558827,"at":"@mrpit", "name":"Pitmen", "content":"This is the first post, There is a bunch of interesting information in here"},
{"id":2,"date":1596827234.901298, "at":"@mrben", "name":"Benman", "content":"This is the second post, pretend there is a bunch of scientific information in here."},
{"id":3,"date":1596827268.411034, "at":"@mrgreen", "name":"The Green Machine", "content":"This is the thrid post, idk what you wanna pretend is here, maybe something political"},
{"id":4,"date":1596834988.94011, "at":"@mrman", "name":"The Man who Can", "content":"And finally we are at the forth post, there is tons going on here, maybe even something offensive."}]
```

and I am trouble since the root object seems to be an array.

I was trying to use something like this

```
struct DataSet: Decodable {
    let post: [SinglePost]
}

struct SinglePost: Decodable{
    let id: Int
    let date: Double
    let at: String
    let name: String
    let content: String
}


 static func getPost(returnWith: @escaping (DataSet?, Bool)->()) {
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let uString = serverUrl
        
        if let url = URL(string: serverUrl + "/post/") {
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data1, response, error in
                if (error != nil) {
                    returnWith(nil, false)
                    return
                }
                
                if let dataString = String(data: data1!, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print(dataString)
                    
                    do {
                        
                        let postSet = try decoder.decode(DataSet.self, from: Data(dataString.utf8))
                        returnWith(postSet, true)
                        
                    }
                        
                    catch let jsonError {
                        print("Error Serializing JSON", jsonError)
                        returnWith(nil, false)
                    }
                } else {
                  returnWith(nil, false)
                }
                
            })
            
            task.resume()
            
        }
    }
```

But this isn't working.

What would be the best way to go about doing this. And sorry I am pretty new to swift so this may have an obvious answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue there is that you are trying to decode a dictionary instead of an array.

Just change

```
let postSet = try decoder.decode(DataSet.self, from: Data(dataString.utf8))
```

to

```
let postSet = try decoder.decode([SinglePost].self, from: Data(dataString.utf8))
```

edit/update:

Regarding your method signature just change it to return an array instead of a DataSet structure and I would return the error instead of a Bool:

```
static func getPost(completion: @escaping ([SinglePost]?, Error?) -> ()) {
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    if let url = URL(string: serverUrl + "/post/") {
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }
            do {
                completion(try decoder.decode([SinglePost].self, from: data), nil)
            } catch {
                print("Error Decoding JSON", error)
                completion(nil, error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
getPost { posts, error in
    guard let posts = posts else {
        print(error ?? "")
    }
    for post in posts {
        print(post)
    }
}
```

Comment: Then what would the return type be changed to?

Comment: Just change the method signature to `static func getPost(returnWith: @escaping ([SinglePost]?, Bool)->()) {` Btw I would change the completionHandler name from returnWith to just completion

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I tried to but it wasnt long enough at the time lol